# Removing idle-python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, python, python-2.7, idle-python

I'm having some issues when updating packages on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 idle-python2.7
Setting up idle-python2.7 (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing idle-python2.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I believe it can be related with `idle-python2.7` and I want to remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove idle-python2.7
```

to see if that fixes it, but I'm afraid I'll bork my system.

Can I safely remove that package? How can I run a "trial removal" to see what would be removed along with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the terminal try running the following command to see what it does:

```
idle-python2.7
```

The command opens a new window of the IDLE (using Python-2.7) Integrated Development Environment for Python. idle-python2.7 is just an application, so it is safe to remove IDLE (using Python-2.7) from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove idle-python2.7
```

Alternatively you could run the following command to simulate what removing idle-python2.7 would do without actually removing anything:

```
apt-get remove --simulate idle-python2.7
```

Comment: Thank you very much @karel, I removed it and the issue went away. If you'd like you can stop by http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150106/importerror-no-module-named-struct-error-when-managing-packages and answer that question too since it's directly related.

Comment: @Gabriel FYI you can run a "trial removal" by adding the `--dry-run` or `-s` (simulate) option i.e. `sudo apt-get remove --dry-run idle-python2.7`

Comment: Great, thanks @steeldriver I knew there was a way to do that!